# Cruise Control .net git log invalid revision range

Tags: git, cruisecontrol.net

I've managed to mess up my Cruise Control projects.

I was updating the Git URLs for the project repositories on my continuous integration server when moving to a new source control host.  I got a bit cut and paste happy and pasted the wrong URL for a repository into the origin.  So the next time Cruise Control did a pull it merged and pulled a lot of stuff that shouldn't be in the repository.

Once I'd realised my mistake, I thought not a problem, I'll just delete the offending repository and clone using the correct URL.

Except that Cruise Control seems to have remembered the last change set from the messed up repository and when deciding if it needs to do a new build it's throwing a hissy fit.  That's what I'm guessing has happened anyway.  When it's issuing a git log command it's saying that it can't find a change set in the cleaned up respository.

The command it's issuing is:

```
git log 66cd57438ea42b4f8cb6dbf033dc1162f61a4d54..origin/master --name-status --pretty=format:"Commit:%H%nTime:%ci%nAuthor:%an%nE-Mail:%ae%nMessage:%s%n%n%b%nChanges:" -m
```

Git's reponse is

```
Source control operation failed: fatal: Invalid revision range 66cd57438ea42b4f8cb6dbf033dc1162f61d5e65..origin/master
```

The changeset id definitely doesn't exist in the correct repository but does exist in the repository I incorrectly merged.

How do I get Cruise Control .net to forget the duff changeset id?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CruiseControl.net stores the id of the last commit in a per-project `state` file.
These are normally text files that reside in the server directory (c:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server)

e.g.
A state file could contain:

```
<IntegrationResult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" scmError="false">
  <ProjectName>Project1</ProjectName>
  ...
  <Label>1.2.3.4</Label>
  <Parameters>
    ...
    <NameValuePair name="$LastChangeNumber" value="66cd57438ea42b4f8cb6dbf033dc1162f61a4d54" />
  </Parameters>
  <LastSuccessfulIntegrationLabel>1.2.3.4</LastSuccessfulIntegrationLabel>
  <SourceControl name="commit" value="66cd57438ea42b4f8cb6dbf033dc1162f61a4d54" />
</IntegrationResult>
```

You can modify this file to contain a commit id thats relevant from your correct repository; however you must stop CruiseControl first. Restart the server/service once they've all been changed and all should be good.

The only line that needs changing is:

```
  <SourceControl name="commit" value="66cd57438ea42b4f8cb6dbf033dc1162f61a4d54" />
```

The other properties can be left as is; they're just properties of the last build.

Comment: Thank you for this. My procedure: stop CC service, delete file, start CC service, Force build, and it worked.

Comment: hahahah, hey @Simon Laing - guess why I'm here! (Paul-V)